# dart, a nice way of replacing keys and values in maps?

Tags: dictionary, dart

I have a `Map` and I want to go through both the `values` and `keys` and replace any occurrences of particular objects which meet some set criteria with some other objects, so if I find a key that meets a specific criteria.
I want to swap that key for a different object that still points at the same value object in the map, similarly if I find a value that I want to replace I want the original key to point at the replacement value.
Here is some code that works for a simplified example but it looks quite ugly, is there a nicer way of achieving this, meaning a method which doesn't require that you extract every key and value you want to replace and then write the replacements back in.
It would be nicer to be able to just iterate of the map once rather than iterating over the keys, and then iterating over all the keys and values to be replaced?

```dart
void main(){
  //replace all values of instance A with an Object and all keys starting with "t" with the same key minus the "t"
  var m = {
    "one": new A(),
    "two": new A(),
    "three": new B(),
    "four": new B()
  };
  mapKeyAndValueSwapper(m,
    keyMeetsCondition: (k) => k.startsWith("t"),
    valueMeetsCondition: (v) => v is A,
    keyReplacer: (k) => k.replaceFirst("t", ""),
    valueReplacer: (v) => new Object());
  print(m);
}

mapKeyAndValueSwapper(Map m, {bool keyMeetsCondition(key), bool valueMeetsCondition(value), dynamic keyReplacer(key), dynamic valueReplacer(value)}){
  var keysToReplace = [];
  var keysToReplaceValuesFor = [];
  var keys = m.keys;
  keys.forEach((k){
    if(keyMeetsCondition != null){
      if(keyMeetsCondition(k)){
        keysToReplace.add(k);
      }
    }
    if(valueMeetsCondition != null){
      if(valueMeetsCondition(m[k])){
        keysToReplaceValuesFor.add(k);
      }
    }
  });
  keysToReplaceValuesFor.forEach((k){
    m[k] = valueReplacer(m[k]);
  });
  keysToReplace.forEach((k){
    m[keyReplacer(k)] = m.remove(k);
  });
}

class A{}
class B{}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this does the same:

```dart
  Map newMap = {};
  m.forEach((k, v) {
    var key = k;
    var value = v;
    if(m[k] is A) {
      value = new Object();
    }
    if(k.startsWith('t')) {
      key = k.replaceFirst('t', '');
    }
    newMap[key]=value;
  });
```

Comment: hmmm, you made me rethink my problem, thanks. maybe creating a new map is the way to go rather than replacing keys and values in the already existing map.

Comment: I thought about `new Map.fromIterable() wher you can apply mapping but you don't have access to `key` and `value` in the mapping function but only `key` in the `key` mapping function and only `value` in the `value` mapping function.

Comment: haivng looked at my code I cant use this solution unfortunately as I don't have access to the original map reference to overwrite with the new map that it would return, I do need to individually replace each individual key/value in the existing map. ah well, nevermind, still a nice solution for many other use cases though

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension on Map that creates a list from the mapEntries and then manipulate that list to update the key (using the index to maintain order), then clear the map and rebuild it from your updated list.

```
extension MapX<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  bool updateKey({required K currentKey, required K newKey}) {
    if (containsKey(currentKey) && !containsKey(newKey)) {
      final value = this[currentKey] as V;
      final index = keys.toList().indexWhere((k) => k == currentKey);

      final mapEntriesList = entries.toList();
      mapEntriesList.removeAt(index);
      mapEntriesList.insert(index, MapEntry<K,V>(newKey, value));

      clear();

      addEntries(mapEntriesList);

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```